# AddtoAny Buttons not been showed

Tags: javascript

I am using AddtoAny buttons to share in my project, but I am using [colorbox node](https://www.drupal.org/project/colorbox_node) to show the webpage I want to share, like a modal windows.

Here is the issue, when I open  the page without the [colorbox node](https://www.drupal.org/project/colorbox_node) module, the addtoany buttons work smoothly, but when I use the [colorbox node](https://www.drupal.org/project/colorbox_node) module, the buttons are not initialized, it looks like is missing something, or some script.

Did anyone have same behavior and how could be fixed?